# Is the order of firestore snapshot events guaranteed?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I have have multiple clients writing to the same document in a transaction, is every transaction triggering the snapshot listener? If yes is it guarenteed that the listener are triggered in the order the transactions are commited? I would expect yes, but am a bit unsure because:

- If a document write is performed the local Snapshot gets notified immediately cause of [latency concerns](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes). Does this "local" notification only get triggered if the transaction is guranteed to be successfull? Otherwise order would not be guaranteed right?
- There is a [onSnapshotsInSync](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Firestore#onsnapshotsinsync) method. Out of the documentation I don't really get if this is related to my question, but the method irritates me a bit. When should this method be considered, is my question somehow related to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that a listener is only triggered, when the transaction is actually completed. And after the transaction is finished, I'd expect all changes to be committed to the database at once.

[onSnapshotInSync](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Firestore#onsnapshotsinsync) only ensures that multiple listeners are in sync with each other.

Comment: I also assumed that but was kinda confused because to determine if a transaction could be successfull there would be a need to contact server to verify no other modification happened. This would lead to the latency that I expect should get avoided by directly notify the local listener. But maybe I just don't get the magic behind it.

According to the onSnapshotInSync. I still dont really get it. Do you may have an example on how to use this function. I cant find one on the web. How do you specify which snapshots should be in sync?

Comment: You can't specify which listeners you want to be in sync, it will always be all listeners. For example, imagine a scenario where you have multiple listeners for one document. When the document is changed, the listeners may be notified slightly delayed of each other. onSnapshotsInSync will fire if all listeners are in sync with each other (regardless of the source of the data, it could be from cache).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Still I am unsure if order is really guranteed as I fould out, at least for cloud-firestore-triggers it is not. see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#limitations